# pycharm keeps connecting to debugger and waiting for connection

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev

pycharm keeps connecting to debugger and waiting for connection.
I use python 2.7 and environment varibles contain 'PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1;PYCHARM_DEBUG=True'.
But the log is like

```
/Users/suncong/.virtualenvs/lalala/bin/python2.7 /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 53235 --file 

/Users/suncong/sc_leetcode/three_sums.py
Using Cython speedups

Executing file /Users/suncong/sc_leetcode/three_sums.py
arguments: ['/Users/suncong/sc_leetcode/three_sums.py']
PYDEVD_FILTER_LIBRARIES False

Started in multiproc mode

('Connecting to ', '127.0.0.1', ':', '53235')
('Connected.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 371, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
Received port 53235

pydev debugger: process 6207 is connecting

('Connecting to ', '127.0.0.1', ':', '53235')
('Connected.',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 371, in _on_run
    r = self.sock.recv(1024)
error: [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
```

I try to remove the folder named .idea, but it does not work.
When I restart my computer, it becomes fine but changes back to the state above after a little time.